# postgresql corr aggregate function returning null

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, correlation

I have two perfectly (or completely imperfectly?) correlated numbers, and i want to find correlation between them. The original scenario is different and more complex, but the problem is somewhere within the method of correlation pg uses. Please consider the following query:

```
    WITH all_series AS (
      select t as id, 'One' as name, 1 as num from generate_series(1, 10) t
      UNION
      select t as id, 'Two' as name, 2 as num from generate_series(1, 10) t
      ORDER BY name, id
    )

    SELECT (t1.name || '|' || t2.name) as names, corr(t2.num, t1.num) c
    FROM all_series t1
    INNER JOIN all_series t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE t1.name > t2.name
    GROUP BY (t1.name || '|' || t2.name)
    ORDER BY (t1.name || '|' || t2.name)
```

If you remove the Group and open selects, the numbers are perfectly aligned, which should give SOMETHING as correlation..  but it gives empty (not even zero).

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want the correlations on the series generated, not on the constant 1:

```
WITH all_series AS (
  select t as id, 'One' as name, 1 as num, t.val from generate_series(1, 10) t(val)
  UNION ALL
  select t as id, 'Two' as name, 2 as num, t.val from generate_series(1, 10) t(val)
  ORDER BY name, id
)
SELECT (t1.name || '|' || t2.name) as names, corr(t2.val, t1.val) c
FROM all_series t1
INNER JOIN all_series t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.name > t2.name
GROUP BY (t1.name || '|' || t2.name);
```

Your version is doing the correlation on `num` which is constant ("1" or "2").  I guess the NULL is resulting from a divide-by-zero in the calculation.  The correlation of two constant columns should be 1, but it is also a degenerate case.

Comment: yes the issue was with all values being exactly the same (not against each other, but the entire series having the same value) ... the denominator being 0, pg gives null and not 1

Comment: @saGii . . . I should mention two things.  (1) I consider this a bug.  (2) It hints that Postgres is implementing a non-numerically stable algorithm for correlation.